# Wooden laundry clip

Tags: vocabulaire, habillement

Quel est le mot qui traduit "wooden clip" en français, un truc en bois pour laisser sécher du linge ?

Comment: On appelle ça une "**pince à linge**" (en bois si tu veux le préciser). https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pince_%C3%A0_linge Quelques fois, on utilise aussi "**épingle à linge**".

Comment: Parles-tu d'un petit objet pour fixer le linge à un fil (pince à linge), ou d'un support pour le poser dessus (étendoir/tancarville) ?

Comment: pour fixer le linge, à savoir 'pince à linge' - la réponse que j'ai eue grâce aux posters ici

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On appelle ça une "**pince à linge**" (en bois si tu veux le préciser) et  quelques fois, on utilise aussi "**épingle à linge**".

> Une pince ou épingle à linge est un objet destiné à maintenir des vêtements mis à sécher sur une corde à linge ou un étendoir.

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pince_%C3%A0_linge)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "épingle à linge", ne serait-ce pas un régionalisme ?

Comment: Non ce n'est pas un régionalisme, c'est juste un terme plus vieux, car auparavant, les épingles à linge n'étaient pas pareil, et ne pincaient pas (un seule pièce sans ressort), elles ont depuis évolué et sont devenues de vraies pinces, mais on a gardé les deux termes. D'ailleurs, le terme anglais pour la pince à linge est aussi clothespin, et pin veut dire épingle alors que clip veut dire pince. Les deux sont tout à fait acceptables.

Comment: Pour info sur le terme épingle à linge : http://e-dition.net/histoire-depingles-a-linge/

Comment: La référence vient quand même de l'Office québéquois de la langue française (qui d'ailleurs en déconseille l'usage), donc ça ne me conforte pas dans l'idée que ce ne soit pas un régionalisme. En cherchant un peu plus sur Internet je ne trouve ce terme utilisé que par des Suisses.

Comment: Le terme déconseillé par l'Office québécois n'est pas **épingle** mais **épingue**, je suis originaire et j'ai vécu en France métropolitaine toute ma vie, et j'ai toujours dit épingle, tout en connaissant les deux bien sûr. De plus wikipédia ne pose aucun jugement sur épingle vs pince et emploi les deux sans réstriction. Dans ce cas là, certains préfèrent l'un ou l'autre, mais les deux sont néanmoins tout à fait acceptables.

Comment: [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/épingle/30463/locution?q=épingle+à+linge#171615) parle d'un synonyme en effet. Le [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8456988) dit bien en effet que c'est _épingue_ et non _épingle_ qui est déconseillé ; on a aussi le _fichoir_, jamais entendu pour ma part. Merci.